# ipython output from file like entered

Tags: python, latex, ipython

When I work in ipython shell for example I get the following output

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: A = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])

In [3]: A
Out[3]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [4]:
```

When I create a similar python file like

```
import numpy
A = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])
A
```

and run it within ipython with %run. I do not get the same output.

What can I do to get the *Out [n]* lines and if possible also the *In [n]* lines. I need the Inputs and Output for a latex document about using ipython for my class.

Comment: Why not just use the ipython shell? What you are asking for is not possible without lots of complex runner code.

Comment: Because I have to copy/paste about 50 lines of python code to ipython shell for the document on every change